# Problem sending JSON data from JQuery to WCF REST method

Tags: wcf, rest, jquery, http-options-method

I'm having some trouble getting jquery to post some json data to a rest method I have on my WCF service.

On the WCF side, here's the operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "PostSomething")]
MyResult PostSomething(MyRequest request);
```

both `MyResult` and `MyRequest` are marked with all the necessary `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes and service is exposing WebHttp endpoint.

On the JQuery side, here's my function call:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(reqObj);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/MyService/PostSomething",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: jsonStr,
    success: function (html) {
        alert(html);
    }
});
```

this request never reaches my method (I get a 405 Method Not Allowed everytime), and looking in Charles the request looks like this:

```
OPTIONS /MyService/PostSomething HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Accept
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.237 Safari/534.10
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

couple of things which is strange about this:

1. the method is OPTIONS not POST
2. the content-type (in another tab) shows `text/html; charset=UTF-8` instead of json
3. the JSON data is no where to be seen

However, if I modify the request in Charles so that its headers is similar to the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/3a7b550d-9ee3-4a8c-8c25-89baa347ae67/), then everything works:

```
POST /MyService/PostSomething HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 152

{"Id":"", "Name":"testspot","Description":"test" }
```

looking at tutorials and other questions on here others have managed to get JQuery to post to a WCF REST method like this, and I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here..

oh, to put some context, this is a WCF 4 service and I'm using JQuery 1.4.4.

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

After some more reading and thanks to Darrel for pointing me towards the cross-domain spec, I managed to get a bit further by making some small changes to my service, on the service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "PostSomething")]
MyResult PostSomething(MyRequest request);
```

and in the implementation, I need to check if the incoming requests is for OPTIONS and in that case return some headers rather than doing the intended work:

```
if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS")
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");

    return null;
}
```

the method then gets called twice, the first time the server returns null but adds some headers to the client, and then the actual request is made with POST as method and the server goes ahead and deals with the request normally.

Comment: I love you so much! So much!!! Cheers!!!
I had to host a WCF at a Windows Service App. The method GET worked but POST never worked until I get Method="*" to make things works. In my case the method is not called twice!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work over here.. Can you put a full example online?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a Firefox thing for avoiding cross domain calls.  See http://www.petefreitag.com/item/703.cfm

The spec for this is here http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ and after a very brief read, it appears that because you are doing a cross domain call, your service is expected to implement the OPTIONS method and return some headers that allow the POST method to be sent.

Comment: thanks! that sounds like a plausible explanation as to why the request looks so different to what I was expecting.

Comment: do you know what I would need to change in my WCF service or JQuery to get it work?

Comment: @theburningmonk You need to implement a handler for OPTIONS

Comment: @DarrelMiller. How can I implement a handler for OPTIONS?

Answer (score 3):

The update on the question containing a proposed solution has some issues - The problem with it is that if your input does not support the POST method, the OPTIONS request is not actually returning the correct allowed headers.  It really isn't looking at which methods are actually allowed on the WCF endpoint - its just artificially saying "POST" is allowed for every single endpoint in the application when a client performs an OPTIONS request (which is really the client asking what is supported).

This is probably OK, if you aren't really relying on the information in the OPTIONS method to return you a valid list of methods (as is the case with some CORS requests) - but if you are, you will need to do something like the solution on this question:
[How to handle Ajax JQUERY POST request with WCF self-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369619/how-to-handle-ajax-jquery-post-request-with-wcf-self-host)

Basically, each endpoint should implement:

`Webinvoke(Method="OPTIONS", UriTemplate="")`

and call an appropriate method which loads the proper headers to the response (including the proper "Access-Control-Allow-Method" list for that endpoint) to the caller. It kind of sucks that hosted WCF endpoints don't do this for us automatically, but this is a workaround that allows finer control over the endpoint. 
In that solution the proper response headers are loaded at the endpoint implementation:

```
public void GetOptions()
    {
        // The data loaded in these headers should match whatever it is you support on the endpoint
        // for your application. 
        // For Origin: The "*" should really be a list of valid cross site domains for better security
        // For Methods: The list should be the list of support methods for the endpoint
        // For Allowed Headers: The list should be the supported header for your application

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    }
```

In addition to that, you should be setting the "CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled" flag either in the web.config for the binding endpoint, or in code for the WebHttpBinding when configuring the endpoint.  Otherwise, you are again lying in your header response when you say "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is "*" (or a list of URLS)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Try putting .svc after MyService so that the URL reads

```
http://localhost/MyService.svc/PostSomething
```

---

I was working on this the other day myself, and came across a post on Rick Strahl's blog:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx

This works flawlessly for me, so give it a try!

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: looking through the article, I'm doing exactly the same thing, the only difference being when he switched to pass the actual data instead of json serialized string

Comment: got a little further it seems, calling http://localhost/MyService.svc/PostSomething returns: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 02 Feb 2011 15:44:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0
but no subsequent calls to the actual method

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config have you used webhttpbinding?

only webhttpbinding supports json.

Comment: no luck, that just moved the location of the method to localhost/MyService/MyService/PostSomething

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post a short answer that helped me, because other answers didn't.

- Scenario: ajax call to wcf service.
- Error cause: automatic OPTIONS request from ajax before sending POST
  request. The first request could not be handled by my service.
- Solution: allow OPTIONS request, and respond to it.

What you need to do:

1. Add this to web.config:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
   ```
2. Add this to Global.asax.cs (if you don't have this file in your solution, then create it by: Add new item => Visual C# => Global Application Class (default name is "Global.asax")):

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   }
   ```