# How to enable CORS via attribute instead of via Application_BeginRequest when preflight is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I've been having a CORS configuration issue for over an hour now and I can't find a question that helps me understand this situation.

I have an XHR firing on a staging domain with a preflight `OPTIONS` request that is returning with a 400, and the POST is not being sent because the CORS header to permit it isn't present.

I have `config.EnableCors();` in my `WebApiConfig.cs` and am using the *NuGet* package `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Cross-Origin Support` (*Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors v5.23*)

I then set a default instead of using the empty constructor, having seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024313/asp-net-webapi2-enable-cors-not-working-with-aspnet-webapi-cors-5-2-3?rq=1) question so the `WebApiConfig` lines are:

```
var defaultCors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(defaultCors);
```

I don't mind this but I'd prefer not setting anything here at all. In any case, this isn't working.

The errors look like this when the `OPTIONS` request is handled by the `Global.asax.cs` but doesn't write the header:

```
OPTIONS http://staging.example.com:8044/Controller/Action
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://staging.example.com:8044/Controller/Action. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://staging.example.co.uk:8044' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The error looks like this when the request isn't handled in the `Global.asax.cs`:

```
OPTIONS http://staging.example.com:8044
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://staging.example.com:8044/Controller/Action. Invalid HTTP status code 400
```

I have been able to access the API cross-domain by using this solution in the `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://staging.example.com:8044");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accepts, Content-Type, Origin, X-My-Header");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

What I actually want to be doing is this:

```
[EnableCors("http://www.example.com", "*", "get,post")]
public sealed class ControllerController : ApiController
{
    [EnableCors("http://staging.example.com:8044,http://www.example.com", "*", "post")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Action([FromBody] ModelledInput input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can't understand why the CORS attribute isn't handling the preflight request, though I understand why the `BeginRequest` is. I want the CORS control to be managed on a controller or action level, not globally. I thought it might be the `HttpPost` attribute but removing that didn't work.

I'm open to the suggestion I have done something wrong or that the request may be being filtered or handled higher up - I'm not certain where to look to address this but I'm not happy to handle CORS globally.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: this link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001846/how-to-handle-options-method-in-asp-net-mvc. It seems to me that you have to allow OPTIONS verb on the server side. Try adding OPTIONS to header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" like in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://staging.example.com:8044");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accepts, Content-Type, Origin, X-My-Header");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

}
```

The code above mentioned worked for me

Comment: But that is almost exactly what OP says they already did which is working. This answers nothing.