# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource shows up on hitting controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have already added the `*` as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but the request yields a 404 saying that

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**My Controller code:**

```
            [AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute]
            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult uploadzip()
            {

                Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");       // Need to add the correct domain in here!!
                Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");   // Only allow POST
                Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "300");          // Cache response for 5 minutes
                Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");         // Ensure this header is also allowed!  

                ...

                return Json(json);
             }
```

I am sure this is the correct way to go.. Is there something missing ?

**The post request below:**

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://site1.com/auth/uploadzip',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/zip',
            success: function (d, t, x) {
                if (d.status == "success") {

                }}});
```

**Even tried the custom attribute way** described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002784/1221203).

**Still the browser complains:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://site1.com/auth/uploadzip. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://site2.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Any more pointers?

Comment: The code you've shown reacts to an HTTP `POST`. But you need to respond to an `OPTIONS` request, first, and specify the access control headers on *that* response in order for the browser to even *perform* the `POST` request.

Comment: @Nezam Search the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001846/how-to-handle-options-method-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Sheepy did that already. See the edit.