# CORS on Web API and MVC 5 Controller: Upload images with fetch and FormData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, cors, asp.net-web-api2, form-data, aurelia-fetch-client

I have an application that has the front and back ends running on different .NET projects. 
The front end is an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) web application running on ASP.NET 5. This Aurelia app (from now on **The FrontEnd**) gets all it's data from a Web API 2/MVC 5 application (henceforth, **The BackEnd**).

Since The FrontEnd and the BackEnd are different applications I have CORS setup, both for the Web API and in the `Start.Auth.cs` for the token bearer request.

The FronEnd is running on `http://localhost:49850`.

Now, for some code (this is all in the BackEnd)

#### Start.Auth.cs

The whole of the application resides behind a log-in form, so inside the `Start.Auth.cs` file, other than setting up the token-based authentication on the `static Startup()`, method I have a bit of middleware that adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the request on the one case where there is no token available yet: when we are requesting one.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/token"))
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost:49850" });
        await next();
     });

     app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
     app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

#### WebApiConfig.cs

Here I just added the `EnableCorsAttribute` so that it is enable globally.

```
var enableCors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:49850", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(enableCors);
```

### Uploading files

Everything works fine; I can perform `GET` and `POST` requests to the Web API without a problem, the problem comes when trying to upload images.

To upload to files I have an action method in an ASP.NET MVC controller called `FileControler`.

#### FileController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(string id, string name = "")
{
    var files = (from string fileName in Request.File
                 select Request.Files[fileName]
                 into file
                 where file != null
                 select DoSomethingWithTheFile(file, id)).ToList();
    // ...

    return Json(arrayWithFileUrls);
}
```

#### Calling the MVC controller

This is already part of The FrontEnd.

To call this method I use [Aurelia's Fetch Client](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client):

```
upload(url, data, files) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
        formData.append(key, data[key]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append(`files[${i}]`, files[i]);
    }

    return this.http.fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            cmsDatabase: sessionStorage["cmsDatabase"]
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And here's a call to the `upload` method above:

```
// files comes from an <input type="file" />
upload("http://localhost:64441/file/uploadImage", { id: id }, files) 
     .then((uploadedPhotos) => {
          // do something with those file urls...
 });
```

### The Problem

All this works if I remove all CORS setup from `WebApiConfig.cs`, and in `Startup.Auth.cs` I substitute the call to the middleware for `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`, so I know my code is ok, but as soon as I use the CORS setup described above, everything works except the call to `http://localhost:64441/file/uploadImage`, returning even a `404`:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:64441/file/uploadForSku. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:49850' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The "funny" thing is that if I try calling that url with, for intance, [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) I don't get a 404.

I've tried adding the `[HttpOptions]` attribute to the action method; I've tried creating `ActionFilterAttributes` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218240/cors-in-asp-net-mvc5) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001846/how-to-handle-options-method-in-asp-net-mvc), and even setting uip CORS from within the `web.config`, but to no avail.

I know the problem is that `FileController` is a regular MVC Controller instead of a Web API controlle, but shouldn't it still be possible to get CORS working?

Comment: did you sort this?

Comment: @sambomartin, nope, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this

```
 context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs file

Comment: I just did, but it made no difference. Where exactly in `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` should I call this?

Comment: here    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)

Comment: Yup, that's where I tried it indeed, unfortunately it didn't work.