# jQuery POST does not send JSON data

Tags: wcf, rest, jquery, post

I'm trying to do a POST to a service running on localhost with jQuery AJAX, but it keeps returning status code 0 even after I've set `jQuery.support.cors = true`. I can also navigate to my WCF REST service successfully from my browser. This is what my JavaScript looks like:

```
    <script>
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8000/Test",
                data: '{"test":"test"}',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error:function(x,e){
                    if(x.status==0){
                        alert('error 0');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I should also mention that I can't POST to anything on localhost using jQuery.

According to Fiddler, the JSON data is not sent, and a HTTP OPTIONS is done instead of a POST.

Comment: Status code 0 means that the process executed without error does it not? What's the problem with 0?

Comment: @3nigma: That didn't work either.

Comment: @sunjay03: It means that there was no response to the request, or that it can't see service at the specified URL. I'd get the same response if I set `$.ajax({url` to an invalid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't want to spend anymore time on this issue, so I resorted to using raw HTML form POST as the usage of JSON wasn't essential in my case.

For anyone else having the same issues outlined in the original post, see this thread for an explanation and a solution: [Problem sending JSON data from JQuery to WCF REST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875195/problem-sending-json-data-from-jquery-to-wcf-rest-method)

To summarize, your service needs to be able to handle the HTTP OPTIONS method if it is expected to respond to cross domain calls.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var dataObj = {test:"test"};

var json = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
```

then in your ajax call

```
data: json,
```

Comment: Thx so much bro! Worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a tool like network monitor etc. to see if the browser is asking the server for the allowed headers (using the OPTIONS header request), you may need to supply the correct headers in an OPTIONS response before the actual request is sent to the server (see the article at the bottom).

Also, you could try adding this to the actual call or the ajaxSetup, as you will need to tell the browser to send credentials and allow the cross domain call (I know someone else already mentioned 'crossDomain'):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

Have a read of this if you get time too.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Answer (score 1):

So, when the request is cross domain, jQuery will send your post request as a get request anyways.
Are you accessing "localhost" in the URL but then your application is sending the requests to the local IP of your machine instead of localhost? Because that's technically cross-domain, which means that you won't receive the request in the expected manner.

E.g. (just tested this locally)
Visiting my local site at:

```
http://localhost/test/
```

A form on the site submits to my local ip address instead of `localhost` via $.post():

```
<form action="http://10.0.0.17/test/" method="post">
   ....[form stuff...]
</form>
```

**This is a cross-domain request**

If you're calling $.post() or jquery's ajax() call set to post, it automatically moves your parameters from the post body into the query string.

If you ARE accessing local host, try hitting the site via whatever address your jquery post() method is using as the domain and see if that helps.

See more on cross-domain policies:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score -2):

Send the data as an Object literal instead of a string

```
data: '{"test":"test"}',
```

to

```
data: {test:"test"},
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm certain that the problem isn't with the JSON. For some reason, jQuery just can't see localhost:8000 even though my browser can.

Comment: Hmm, well i would make this alteration anyway.  As for the lack of communication.  Perhaps it believes its a cross domain request.  If so you could benefit from a JSONP callback.  Look into that.

Comment: There is communication between jQuery and the service. However the problem is that although some sort of a request to the specified URL is made, the JSON data is never sent. This results in an HTTP 405.

Comment: rafale, I was just reading up on the same origin policy.  If that request is being made to a different port (ie. :8000), then it violates the same origin policy and won't be able to access the information without a workaround.  The jsonp callback method should work for you.  Let us know if you're still having this problem

Comment: I've got access to the server, so I could simply change its port instead. Would 80 or 8080 be better choices?