# jQuery cross domain post to WCF 4.0 REST service

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, wcf-rest

I'm trying to post JSON data from JQuery to a cross domain WCF 4.0 REST service and cannot get past the cross domain aspect.  Here's my REST method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*",
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "Save")]
    DataContract Save(DataContract dataContract);
```

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax(
{
type: 'POST',
url: url,
data: JSON.stringify(data),
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function(data)
{
    alert('success');
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
{
    alert(xhr.status);  
    alert(thrownError);
} });
```

I've stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875195/problem-sending-json-data-from-jquery-to-wcf-rest-method) but could not get it to work.  Please help.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, in IIS 7, I created a "sub application" to my web site named "Rest" and pointed it to where my WCF Rest Service code lives (in my case C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RestServices).  Then I changed all of my service calls in my website to use the same domain but appended "\Rest\" to the URL.

URL to website:
http://local.companyapp.com/

URL to REST Services:
http://local.companyapp.com/Rest/ServiceLibrary/Save

Before, I was trying to access:
http://local.RestServices.com/ServiceLibrary/Save

It wasn't working because it was a different domain(local.RestServices.com) it was failing.  Changing IIS to have a "sub application" named "Rest" that points to where my Rest Services resides fixes the problem.

I'm not sure what issue I will run into once I'm ready to promote this to production.  On the surface I like this approach because it doesn't force me to modify my code to handle the weirdness surrounding cross domain requests.

Any comments on this is much appreciated.  Thanks