# Issue when consuming a WCF REST service via jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, rest

I've been searching long for an answer (on SO too; I know this is not a properly "fresh" question) but I did not find a solution to my problem yet. I have a WCF REST service, defined as follows:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       UriTemplate = "json/getUserOperations")]
Response<List<Operation>> GetUserOperations();
```

with this web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WS_REST.DataServiceBehavior">
                 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>     
            </behavior>      
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WS_REST.DataServiceBehavior" name="WS_REST.DataService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WS_REST.IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This works well if called from browser. But if I call this in jquery ajax, as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:1996/DataService.svc/json/getUserOperations",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processdata: true,
        success: processReceivedData,
        error: onError,
        complete: function () { alert('completed'); }

 });
```

the service returns me a "405 Method not allowed" message. These are the headers of the request and of the response message:

```
    OPTIONS http://localhost:1996/DataService.svc/json/getUserOperations HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:1996
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Connection: keep-alive
    Origin: http://localhost:2100
    Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
    Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
    Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 16:28:58 GMT
    X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0bd0cdyhwyvmuauqcbasvp45; path=/; HttpOnly
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 1024
    Connection: Close
```

So I fell into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875195/problem-sending-json-data-from-jquery-to-wcf-rest-method), finding out that it could be some issue related to cross-domain calls, and then I modified my OperationContract as follows:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       UriTemplate = "json/getUserOperations")]
Response<List<Operation>> GetUserOperations();
```

In this way, the request seems to be correctly served, as the headers show:

```
    OPTIONS http://localhost:1996/DataService.svc/json/getUserOperations HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:1996
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Connection: keep-alive
    Origin: http://localhost:2100
    Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
    Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 16:45:19 GMT
    X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=as4tch55yulzc32fzxsefh2y; path=/; HttpOnly
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 793
    Connection: Close
```

The response message actually contains the valid json data which I requested. By the way, the jquery.ajax function still trigger the error event... I don't understand why, as the response seems correctly received.
Does anyone notice something wrong?

Regards!

Comment: Your javascript shows "type: "GET"" but the header show 'OPTIONS'. That's strange.

Comment: Read the "preflighted requests" paragraph; options is involved in cross-domain calls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jQueryWCFRest.aspx

I've done as explained in "The cross-domain issue" paragraph and all works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was implementing my Rest WCF service and it looks like you had everything I had except:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GuessWhat/{variable}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

I use that instead of the WebInvoke attribute.  I use WebInvoke if I want to do an HTTP Post.

I am not sure if that will work for you, but that seemed to fix my problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not make difference... By the way I think that WebGet is the same as WebInvoke with method = "GET".

Answer (score 0):

For jquery ajax calls i guess you need to have the below endpoint behaviour configuration:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="web">
             <enableWebScript />
         </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```