# How to handle Ajax JQUERY POST request with WCF self-host

Tags: wcf, jquery, http-post, wcf-data-services

There are many reasons create a RESTful WCF server (it is easy) and even better if you can avoid ASP and it's security box (if all you are doing is simple requests to return information). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750530.aspx on how to do this.

What I found is that handling AJAX (JQUERY) GET requests is easy. But dealing with JSON in a POST is tricky.

Here is an example of a simple GET request contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    String Version();
```

And  the implementaion is here (which returns a JSON)

```
    public partial class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    public String Version()
    {
        mon.IsActive = true;
        this.BypassCrossDomain();
        ViewModel.myself.TransactionCount++;
        return ViewModel.myself.VersionString;
    }
}
```

Ah, but what if you want to POST some JSON. You will find lots of articles on stack overflow that tell you all you have to do is this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    BuildResponse BuildToby(BuildRequest request);
```

which will receive a JSON message, de-serialize into a Plain .NET object (PONO) and let you work with it. And indeed, this worked fine when I constructed the request in Fiddler.

```
POST /BuildToby HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:4326
Content-Length: 1999
```

However, when you use the following AJAX in JQUERY 1.8, you will find a SURPRISE:

It by specifying content-type of "application/json" you will find that there is a "preflight" check that is fired off by the browser to see if you are allowed to POST something other than a www-url-encloded post message. (there are [notes in stack overflow about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest)).

```
    var request = JSON.stringify({ FrameList: ExportData.buildList });
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:4326/BuildToby",
    data: request,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

and here is what fiddler reports: (Note it is not a POST message, but a OPTIONS message).

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:4326/BuildToby HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4326
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://ysg4206
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

What has happened is that a browser (in this case Firefox) has to make a extra call to the server, with a OPTIONS HTTP message, to see if a POST is allowed (of this content type).

All the articles about fixing this are about [editing GLOBAL.ASAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest) which is fine if you are in ASP.NET but are useless if you are doing a self-host WCF.

So now you see the question (sorry for being so long winded, but I wanted to make this a complete article so that others can follow the results).

Comment: In the Mono framework for this, it looks like no matter what I use, the OPTIONS request hangs indefinitely. Was this something you saw while implementing this? It's certainly been awhile

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, now there are some real MSDN gurus out there who have written solutions, but I cannot figure them out:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx

But I have come up with a simple solution. At least in WCF 4.5 you can add your own OperationContract for dealing with OPTIONS requests:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "*")]
    void GetOptions();
```

Note that the method signature is void, and has no arguments. This will get called first, and then the POST message will be called.

The implementation of GetOptions is:

```
    public partial class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    public void GetOptions()
    {
        mon.IsActive = true;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    }
}
```

and that is really all you have to do.

You might also want to add this attribute to your service class, so that you can serialize large JSON:

```
//This defines the base behavior of the CatalogService. All other files are partial classes that extend the service
[ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647)]       // Allows serialization of very large json structures
public partial class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    PgSqlMonitor mon = new PgSqlMonitor();

    private void BypassCrossDomain()
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

Note I have a little helper method called BypassCrossDomain() which I call on all my POST and GET methods, so that I can deal with cross domain calls.

I spent a lot of research time here (in MSDN forums, stack overflow, blogs) and I hope this will help others trying to do these sorts of projects.

Comment: Thanks, the BypassCrossDomain bit above helped sort out a cross domain problem I was having.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.  I used it to call some https services from an http context and it worked great!

Comment: seems to just by sending a blank response for me! No headers no nothing!

Comment: Thanks.It worked. Where from you got this magic GetOptions? Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: If I could upvote this 100 times I would.  This is an excellent solution for building AJAX services using WCF.  Other (not so elegant) solutions involve stuff like intercepting the request and throwing an HTTP exception with a 200 code.

Comment: Does not work for me on WCF 4.6. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

One other addition to Dr.YSG's answer, if you need to support the OPTIONS method on endpoints which take POSTS to individual IDs, you will have to implement multiple GetOptions methods:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "")]
    void GetOptions();
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "{id}")]
    void GetOptions(string id);
```

Its really disappointing that WCF/Microsoft can't automatically generation the proper OPTIONS response based on the signature of the endpoint automatically, but at least it can be handled manually.

Comment: Is there any uservoice request for this feature not implemented properly in WCF?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Dr.YSG listed as his answer, I found that I was getting a Firefox notice that a redirect was occurring, and a "405 Method Not Allowed" error. Adding

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
```

to the GetOptions class seems to have addressed the issue.

Comment: For anyone reading this years later and finding nothing is working, I've been trying various options for hours. Nothing worked until I put that first line of code (allow-origin) *in the body of my WCF method*. (Not in some GetOptions() method.)

Answer (score 0):

After many days searching about it and reading many posts and proposed solutions, i think this question by Dr. YSG was the best resource to understand and solve my problem with angular/wcf/post/CORS etc.

But what really worked for me was this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I understand it is not a full (nor beautiful) solution, since i am using global.asax and there are so many possible scenarios, but i just want to share this alternative, since it may help somebody else eventually.

(Besides adding the headers)