# Enabling CORS between Ajax and WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, http-headers, httprequest

**Problem**

Whenever I try to sent a `POST` request to my WCF service (running locally on IIS), I get:

> Access Denied

**My WCF config (relevant code only)**

I added the below to allow the different methods, and I'm able to get the info from a `Request Method: 'GET'`, but not a `POST`

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Ajax call**

Here is my ajax call, whenever I try to create a new `'Project'`

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseAddress + "projects/create",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'Title': 'Test Title',
        'Customer': {
            'Name': 'Test Name'
        }
    })
})
```

**Service implementation**

Here's the `IService.cs` with the `UriTemplate` and the `Method = 'POST'`

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/projects/create")]
int CreateProject(ProjectDTO project);
```

**EXTRA INFO**

Whenever I watch the headers through google chrome, I see the `Request Method` is `OPTIONS` and the response `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE`, but still, I can't make `POST` requests (Refer to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wkFm.jpg)).

How do I handle the request method `OPTIONS` correctly in a WCF service?

**EDIT**

The funny thing is that the response says: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, etc.`, which means that since the request asks: `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST`, it should be allowed to sent this request, but for some reason I get this `Access Denied`

**EDIT 2**

I'm aware that the `Request Method: OPTIONS`, but the `OPTIONS` asks my service if it's allowed to do a `POST` request, where the service answers back with `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, etc.` There by saying `POST` **IS** allowed.

Comment: Shouldn't "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" contain "Accept, Content-Type, Origin" (missing Origin)?

Comment: @UncleRico Doesn't make any difference either way though :)

Comment: Your headers otherwise look like they should.  Have you tried using a manual header override in the projects/create controller [ie: Response.AppendHeader(...)] ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Like here: http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html.  Can you put a copy of your C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr.log from the 172.20.40.125 server here?  It may not be an issue with the headers at all but a piece of code within the projects/create controller.

Comment: There's a bunch of crap in there and most of it is just localhost. This is what the cross origin looks like: `2015-09-01 12:53:55 172.20.40.125 2028 172.20.40.125 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -`

Answer (score 0):

Will it Support `OPTIONS` request? According to CORS, the first request will be preflight request. i.e OPTIONS to verify and the next `GET,POST` will be success based on `OPTIONS` response headers.

Please refer more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I tried this: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE, OPTIONS" />` as well. But no difference. By sending the `OPTIONS` it asks 'May I send `POST`?' and as the `Allow-Method` has `POST` in it, it should be allowed but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a WCF service that I needed to call from a JavaScript client via AJAX - so I first added an endpoint with a 'webHttpBinding' to allow access over pure HTTP (i.e. no SOAP, see this answer if curious: [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)).

Then, this is how I enabled CORS for my WCF service:

1. Add a Global.asax file (if you don't have one already)
2. Implement the following method:

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Add CORS headers to allow a JavaScript client to call the WCF service via AJAX from a different domain
       var requestOrigin = Request.Headers.Get("Origin");
       Log.Debug($"Processing request from Origin: '{requestOrigin}'");

       // Accommodate for all possible cross-domain requests
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestOrigin) == false)
       {
           if (requestOrigin.Contains("devdomain"))
           {
               AddAllowedOrigin("http://devdomain");
           }
           else if (requestOrigin.Contains("qasdomain"))
           {
               AddAllowedOrigin("http://qasdomain");
           }
           else if (requestOrigin.Contains("prddomain"))
           {
               AddAllowedOrigin("http://prddomain");
           }
       }

       // Respond to an OPTIONS pre-flight request
       if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
       {
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
           HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
       }
   }

   private static void AddAllowedOrigin(string origin)
   {
       Log.Debug($"Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to response to allow Origin: '{origin}'");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
   }
   ```

Note that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header has to be added to the response to the both the OPTIONS pre-flight request, and every subsequent request sent from the cross-domain (e.g. 'devdomain' etc)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to all the methods in the WCF Service.

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Requires the following import

```
System.ServiceModel.Web;
```

[Refer this for original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369619/how-to-handle-ajax-jquery-post-request-with-wcf-self-host)