# How to post data from Angular 2 to a ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to combine a ASP.NET Core with my Application (Angular 2), what is the request-command to get the insert data from Angular 2 in the database from ASP.NET Core?

If you have a better idea to combine ASP.NET Core with Angular 2 then send your idea, please.

Everything is build up in Visual Studio 2015 (ASP.NET Core) and Visual Studio Code (Angular 2 Application).

Comment: Cool, so you have a Angular 2 frontend and want to post data to your ASP.NET backend? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i do not know what can i try, first i try to combine the angular 2 app in the ASP.NET Core, but that failed, and yes i want to get the request from Angular app and work with that in ASP.NET Core, so that i can add, delete, update the database.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369619/how-to-handle-ajax-jquery-post-request-with-wcf-self-host) will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the tour docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: i do the Heroes example, on this example i create the Angular 2  Application.