# Jquery $.post not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code on my site that is called when a user saves a bookmark:

```
function addbookmark(id, col) {
      var action = 'addbookmark';
      var username = '<?php echo $log_username; ?>';
        $("#addbookmark"+id).html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>');
         $.post('https://xxxxxxx/bookmarks_system.php', { username: username , id: id, column: col, action:action },
          function(data) {
           $("#addbookmark"+id).hide();
           $("#removebookmark"+id).show()
           $(".fade_notification").text('Bookmark saved');
           $(".fade_notification").delay(100).fadeIn(250);
           $('.fade_notification').delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
          });
  }
```

This code is working fine on my chrome browser on my laptop, but for some reason it doesn't work when I open the site on my mobile browser (chrome on Android). When I click the button on my mobile, it won't post the data for some reason and keeps showing the spinner icon that is shown when the data is not yet posted.

Anyone who can see why it would not be working on chrome on android?

Comment: Start by adding code to handle if the request fails, so see if it fails for some reason.
And use the remote debugging functionality of chrome to check the console for any errors.

Comment: Any chance to be CORS / OPTIONS issues? [like this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369619/how-to-handle-ajax-jquery-post-request-with-wcf-self-host/39410528#39410528) Probably not.

Comment: Is it on your localhost?

Comment: i think you need to use in this fashion "username": username , "id": id, "column": col, "action":action.   hope it will work

Comment: change username:username   to "username":username and so on

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for the help, saved my day! @user5405873